# How to convert CoyoteInputStream to FileInputStream?

Tags: java, spring, fetch

I send from frontend on js file *.xls to backend using fetch:

```
const invokeImportPaymentsUpload = file => fetch("/rest/import", {
  method: "POST",
  credentials: "same-origin",
  body: file,
});
```

I have rest services on java+spring, so I expected to receive FileInputStream and parse file, but using request.getInputStream() received CoyoteInputStream.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/import"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public Map<String, List<Payment>> importPayments(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
            ImportOutcome outcome = myService.import(request.getInputStream());
            ...
```

How to make from CoyoteInputStream -> FileInputStream to read it and parse?

I have some legacy on backend by parsing FileInputSrtream like this
 byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(fileInputStream);
But it used in other places, it's better to add in my case other new parsing?

Comment: Why would it have to be a `FileInputStream`? Shouldn't any code using the stream just expect any `InputStream`?

Comment: @Andreas I have some legacy on backend, edited description.

Comment: Does legacy mean unmodifiable? Can't you change that code from using `FileInputStream` to using `InputStream`? It should be as simple as changing parameter type, and is fully backwards compatible with existing calls to the method.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be a FileInputStream because the data does not reside in a file on disk.

If you require it to be on disk then you will have to copy the data from the `CoyoteInputStream` to disk and then pass a `FileInputStream` to the code that needs it.

***However***, note that `IOUtils.toByteArray()` only needs an `InputStream`, not a `FileInputStream`.  If the code in which the `toByteArray()` call exists is currently written to require a `FileInputStream` then it is broken code and needs to be modified to work with `InputStream`, in which case your problems disappear.